# String Result is "Infinity" - Android Studio & Java

Tags: java, android, infinity

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            int weight_position=spinner_weight.getSelectedItemPosition();
            int height_position=spinner_height.getSelectedItemPosition();

            double converted_height=height_position/100;
            double doubleHeight=converted_height*converted_height;
            double body_mass_index= weight_position/doubleHeight;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "result is: "+body_mass_index, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Hello, I was trying to develop a simple ideal weight calculator via spinners.
First spinner for weight (kg)
Second spinner for height (cm)
Output(toast message) is; "result is Infinity"

Comment: `doubleHeight` is zero, `weight_position` is positive.

Comment: Thanks but I can't get it clearly. Can you be little more specific?

Comment: Use `height_position/100.0` instead. `height_position < 100`, it would appear, so `height_position/100 == 0`.